# Simple read function error

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I imagine this is something silly I've missed but I've asked my whole class and noone can seem to work it out. Making a simple program calling in a subroutine and I'm having trouble with the do loop reading in the entries of the matrix.

```
program Householder_Program

use QR_Factorisation
use numeric_kinds

complex(dp), dimension(:,:), allocatable :: A, Q, R, V
integer :: i, j, n, m

print *, 'Enter how many rows in the matrix A'
read *, m

print *, 'Enter how many columns in the matrix A'
read *, n

allocate(A(m,n), Q(m,n), R(n,n), V(n,n))

do i = 1,m

    do j = 1,n

        Print *, 'Enter row', i, 'and column', j, 'of matrix A'
        read *, A(i,j)

    end do

end do

call Householder_Triangularization(A,V,R,n,m)

print *, R

end program
```

It will ask me for A(1,1) but when I type in a number it will not ask me for A(1,2), it will leave a blank line. When I try to put in a 2nd number it will error and say :

```
 Enter row           1 and column           1 of matrix A
 1
 2
 At line 22 of file HouseholderProgram.f90 (unit = 5, file = 'stdin')
 Fortran runtime error: Bad repeat count in item 1 of list input
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable `A` is (an array) of type complex.  This means that when you attempt to do the list-directed input of the element values you cannot just specify a single number.  So, in your case the problem is not with the program but with the input.

From the Fortran 2008 standard, 10.10.3

> When the next effective item is of type complex, the input form consists of a left parenthesis followed by an ordered pair of numeric input fields separated by a comma (if the decimal edit mode is POINT) or semicolon (if the decimal edit mode is COMMA), and followed by a right parenthesis.

Input, then, must be something like `(1., 12.)`.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to read in *complex* numbers (`A` is complex)! As such, you should specify complex numbers to the code... Since you are providing just one integer, the program does not know what to do.

Providing `(1,0)` and `(2,0)` instead of `1` and `2` will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

In case the user input is always real, and you want to read it into a complex type array you can do something like this:

```
    Print *, 'Enter row', i, 'and column', j, 'of matrix A'
    read *, dummy
    A(i,j)=dummy
```

where `dummy` is declared `real`. This will save the user from the need to key in the parenthesis required for complex numbers.  ( The conversion to complex is automatic )